# How to set the $EDITOR to Brackets

Tags: terminal, editor, environment-variables

I am trying to set my default editor to Brackets in the Terminal. I tried with

```
 export EDITOR="/Applications/Brackets.app"
```

and when I try to edit a function from the MongoDB Shell it complains that the editor is a directory. I tried giving different paths, but I cannot find the right combination. Please help, I don't want to edit in the Terminal :) :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not on a mac, but I was able to download and examine the contents of the Brackets installer and `Brackets.app` is indeed a directory. Have you tried

```
export EDITOR=/Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/MacOS/Brackets
```

or something similar?

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thanks a lot. Just a minor - it is ApplicationS. Maybe it will be nice to fix it - just if someone else tries it.

Comment: Good catch. I've made the change.